# FileNotFoundException installing Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

Im installing glassfish v2, but when installer is unpacking the jar file the following error messages appear on command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files>java -Xmx256m -jar glassfish-installer-v2ur2-b04-windows.jar<br>
glassfish<br>
glassfish\bin <br>
glassfish\docs <br>
glassfish\docs\css <br>
glassfish\docs\figures <br>
glassfish\docs\graphics <br>
glassfish\imq <br>
glassfish\imq\bin <br>
glassfish\imq\demo <br>
glassfish\imq\demo\applications <br>
glassfish\imq\demo\applications\mqapplet <br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: glassfish\bin\cliutil. <br>
dll (Access is denied) <br>
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) <br>
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) <br>
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) <br>
        at org.jvnet.poormans_installer.Main.install(Main.java:120) <br>
        at org.jvnet.poormans_installer.Main.main(Main.java:69) <br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your user account has administrator privileges

Comment: Yes, it has admin privileges

Comment: run cmd.exe as Administrator, dir to your .jar file and run the command java -Xmx256m -jar glassfish-installer-v2.1.1-b31g-windows.jar

Comment: I did it and it works. Besides i changed the VM and I could install it.